# Create heatmap from 2D array C++

Tags: c++, image, opencv

I have a 2D array that can take the following values:  `0,1,3,5,8,16,27,49,86,149,273,499,898,1537`

How could I create an image representing this discrete value image (lets say a heatmap)?

I have not found any easy way online.
I cannot make something like:

```
void plotImage(const std::vector<short int>& image){
    int min_value = *min_element(image.begin(), image.end());
    int max_value = *max_element(image.begin(), image.end());
    float range =  max_value - min_value;
    // ... Don't know how to create heatmap
}
```

Because the range of integers is not linear so all smaller values (0,1,3,5,...) would end up being 0

---

### EDIT

Following recommendation by @brc-dd I have used https://github.com/lucasb-eyer/libheatmap but this is not exactly what I am looking for because for this package I have to do:

```
void Data::plotImage(int counter, const std::vector<short int>& image){

    heatmap_t* hm = heatmap_new(Nx, Ny);
    for(unsigned i = 0 ; i < image.size() ; ++i) {
        short int val = image[i];
        for (int j=0;j<val;j++){
            heatmap_add_point(hm, i%Nx, i/Nx);
        }
    }
    // ...
}
```

But this is too costly as I already know the value (heat) of each pixel and doing this I get a value, i.e. 1537, so I loop to add the same pixel 1537 times which does not make sense

Comment: There are thousands of such programs and libraries which can be helpful. You are expected to do the research before asking question on stack overflow. For example [this](https://github.com/lucasb-eyer/libheatmap) library or maybe `gnuplot`. I'm personally fond of OpenGL, though it requires much coding, but it's highly customisable. Just search ***heatmap in c++*** you will get thousands of results.

Comment: Actually its hard to find a well documented example (I already tried) and for example for gnuplot there is very little new information on how to use it in C++ project

Comment: I agree that there is not much documentation available for beginners. But `Qt`, `OpenCV`, `OpenGL`, `gnuplot` are the best options. Try posting a new question or edit the tags to include one of these, then you may get more precise answers. But certainly none of them will be "easy". The library whose link I provided in the earlier comment can work for you. You just need its `heatmap_add_point` function. There are examples also present in the repo.

Comment: Hey @brc-dd thanks for your tips, I assume you are not very familiar with the library you have passed me the link to, but there it is assume that at heatmap_add_point you add one point at a time and at the end the heat of that position will depend on how many points fell into that cordinate, how could I set the value for each cordinate directly? As they are my values.

    heatmap_t* hm = heatmap_new(Nx, Ny);
    for(unsigned i = 0 ; i < image.size() ; ++i) {
        short int val = image[i];
        for (int j=0;j<val;j++){
            heatmap_add_point(hm, i%Nx, i/Nx);} }
This is slow

Comment: here you go: use `heatmap_add_weighted_point(hm, x, y, w)`. this is same as adding`w` times `(x, y)` in `hm`. [documentation](https://github.com/lucasb-eyer/libheatmap#using-weighted-datapoints)

Comment: Thanks a lot man, People like you makes this platform great. Much appreciated

Comment: you can increase the rendering speed if its slow: https://github.com/lucasb-eyer/libheatmap#faq Also I would like to quote a line from documentation: *Adding a point with a weight of 3.0 has exactly the same effect as adding that point three times without a weight, but is **(almost) as efficient** as adding a single unweighted point.*

Comment: If you are not satisfied with this library (as I haven't used it at all), you can also raise a question like [this](https://forum.qt.io/topic/108057/plot-heat-map-using-qt) on forums.qt.io.

Comment: You can also use CERN's `root` library, which can make a heatmap with less than 10 lines. Which is the most powerful tool in visualizing scientific data.